# Proof that a subgroup of index $2$ is normal: left versus right coset clarification

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

I am trying to prove the following result.

> Let $H \subset G$  be any subgroup of a finite group $G$. Show that if $|G|/|H| = 2$ then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

The first thing I am not completely sure about is whether the index $|G|/|H|$ typically refers to left cosets, right cosets, or both. I believe the construction of Lagrange's theorem typically uses left cosets; the number of left cosets always equals the number of right cosets, so this could be unambiguously interpreted as the number of cosets, left or right. Am I correct that this proof, in full rigor, requires a lemma that $|G|/|H|$ can refer to both left and right cosets (i.e., so that the Lagrange-theorem construction can be done with both?).

Here is my attempt, taking this result for granted.

> It suffices to show that $gH = Hg$ for all $g \in G$. Given $g \in H \subset G$, we clearly have $gH = Hg = H$. Indeed, if $g \in H$, then $gH \subset H$ since any element of $gH$ is of the form $gh'$ for some $h \in H$ and $H$, a subgroup, is closed under products. Similarly, $Hg \subset H$. Furthermore, given $h \in H$, we have $h = g\left(g^{-1} h\right) = \left(hg^{-1}\right)g$, where $g^{-1} h, hg^{-1} \in H$, so $H \subset Hg, gH$, and we have $gH = Hg = H$. If, on the other hand, $g \not \in H$, then we have $gH = G \setminus H = Hg$ since the left and right cosets of $H$ in $G$ partition $G$ and there are exactly two left cosets and two right cosets by assumption. Therefore, $gH = Hg$ for all $g \in G$, so $H$ is normal.

If people agree that I should add the lemma about cosets, I can amend this post with an attempt at it. I'm not sure if that would be better placed in a separate question, though.

Answer (score 4):

> The first thing I am not completely sure about is whether the index |G|/|H| typically refers to left cosets, right cosets, or both.

That's not index. It is literally the division of $|G|$ by $|H|$. For finite groups it coincides with index (typically denoted by $[G:H]$ or $|G/H|$) by Lagrange, but literally this is not index. The distinction is somewhat relevant since Lagrange works for infinite groups as well where $|G|/|H|$ is not valid (for infinite groups Lagrange is stated as $|G|=[G:H]\cdot |H|$, note that multiplication on infinities is ok but division is not).

> I believe the construction of Lagrange's theorem typically uses left cosets; the number of left cosets always equals the number of right cosets, so this could be unambiguously interpreted as the number of cosets, left or right.

Exactly, when counting these are always the same. The following mapping $gH\mapsto Hg$ is a well defined bijection between (the sets of) left and right cosets for any subgroup $H\subseteq G$ (with $G$, $H$ finite or not). And so if Lagrange works for one side (and it does) then it works for both.

The proof you've shown us looks correct to me.